# Swipe gesture on section header intercepted by trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAtIndexPath of cells underneath

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I add a subview to the section header in viewForHeaderInSection(). Then attach a swipe left gesture to this subview. In this subview, I add a few buttons so when swipe they will show up.

I do this because there is no equivalent for section header of trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAtIndexPath for cells/rows.

All works well until the section header is floated (by scrolling the table up) to the very top of the table view. Now if I try to swipe the section header (subview), the trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAtIndexPath() method of the cell/row underneath the header is invoked instead.

I tried many tweaks but none is working, including setting the zposition of the subview to MAXFLOAT.

Any input is appreciated.

Comment: may be this can help, check if the cell that invoked the swipe is not visible then execute the gesture action of the view in the header

Comment: @NizarAhmed Thx. Will try it.

Comment: @NizarAhmed Yes, it works. Actually I checked the first two (since my section header height is less than cell height) visible cells that might be under/overlapping the section header. If the swipe happens on any of the two, just returning [[UISwipeActionsConfiguration alloc] init]; in trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAtIndexPath method. Thx!

Comment: happy to hear that :)